# PHP Method Check if used for assignment

Tags: php, methods, echo, return-value, variable-assignment

I am not sure if this is possible, however, can we build a method that returns or echo the result based on calling the method directly or used in assignment

```
function foo()
{
    return "bar";
}

$abc = foo();
// $abc will have the value "bar"
```

But if foo() is called directly, it should echo "bar"

```
foo();
// should echo / print "bar"
```

adding echo before foo() solves the problem, but how could this be achieved without using echo. Probably adding some line of code to the function foo()

Comment: Method itself has no idea how it will be used in outer scope (it may be in expression, in single call, in assignment or even in some thing like `eval()` )

Comment: @AlmaDo, thanks! however, there should be something i can manage the default method behaviour based on how it is called

Comment: You can pass some parameter to function for decide functionality

Comment: Ok. Good luck with `$x = function() { return call_user_func(chr(102).str_repeat('o', 2)); }; eval('echo $x();');`

Answer (score 1):

There is a possible way is to echo inside your function .
Just like

```
<?php function foo()
{
    echo "bar";
    return "bar";
}

 echo $abc = foo();
?>
```

Comment: this would not work. if we use `$abc = foo();` to get value into $abc, it would echo the value as well.